# 2 Different Solutions to the same Problem?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

From "A First Course in Probability" textbook, chapter 1 combinatorial analysis, theoretical exercises, problem number 5.
Determine the number of vectors $(x_1,x_2 ,. . . , x_n)$, such that
each $x_i$ is either $\ 0\ $ or $\ 1\ $ and $$\begin{align} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\ x_i \ \ge\  k\end{align} $$
My Solution was to think of it as: first we want the sum of the vectors to be more than or equal $\ k\ $ so at least there sum must be equal to $\ k\ $ and this could be done by choosing $\ k\ $ vectors from the total $\ n\ $ vectors and give them the value $\ 1\ $ and then there will be $\ (n - k)\ $ vectors that can be either $\ 0\ $ or $\ 1\ $ and this equal to $\ 2^{(n - k)}\ $ then the final answer will be: $${^{N}C_{k}}\ .\ 2^{(n - k)}$$
But the solutions are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCETH.jpg)

Comment: You are counting the same several times. E.g. with $n=7,k=2$: $\color{green}{11}\color{red}{11000}$ and $\color{green}1\color{red}1\color{green}1\color{red}{1000}$.

Comment: Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overcounting. Let's say $n=3, k=1$. So we are looking at nonzero $3$-sized vectors, of which there will be $7$. Your calculation produces the number $3\cdot 4=12$.

How did that happen? For example, you are counting $(1,1,1)$ three times: once when the "chosen" $1$ is the first one, and the other two $1$'s happen to have the values $1,1$, then again when the "chosen" $1$ is the *second* one, then again when the "chosen" $1$ is the third one. Similarly, you are counting each of $(1,1,0), (0,1,1), (1,0,1)$ twice.